# Create-react-app build is not working in server : Error: Minified React error #130;

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build, create-react-app, build-error

I have a piece of create-react-app code, Issue is while I'm running the app in localhost it is working well but while I'm running the build in my server then it is not working.

same issue while serving local build

[image]

Getting this only :(

The full text of the error you just encountered is:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
```